# Nilpotency of the Cartan Subalgebra : how can we diagonalise the generators?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let us consider a semi-simple Lie Algebra $L$ and its Cartan subalgebra $H$, which is defined as the maximal nilpotent abelian subalgebra of $L$ such that all its elements are diagonalizable in the Adjoint representation. So, let's choose the basis where $ad_X$ are diagonals, where $X\in H$.

Now, thank's to Engel, we know that an algebra $H$ is nilpotent if its elements are ad-nilpotent, then

$$
(ad_{X})^n Y = 0, \text{for } X \in H \text{ and } Y \in H
$$

I don't understand how we can have $(ad_{X})^n =0$ for $X$ in the Cartan subalgebra if these matrices are diagonal.

Comment: These two concepts "live" different places. In the first case you are considering the adjoint action on the entire Lie algebra, whereas Engel's theorem states this when you consider only the subalgebra (and yes, the adjoint action of any element in the cartan is $0$ when restricted to the Cartan itself, since this is an abelian subalgebra).

Comment: Or in other words, H is the eigenspace to eigenvalue 0 for all those $ad_X$. One could say, "where they have 0's on the diagonal".